# Display multiple values in one column based on values in multiple columns in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table in Excel with 6 columns:

Building_ID, No Accounts (blanks), Active Accounts, No Account Status (NULL), Count and Analysis Outcome. The values of these columns, apart from Analysis Outcome column, are numeric based on count of duplicated values from original source (basically, I pivoted the original table into something that I'm describing here).

I need to populate the Analysis Outcome column with these four statuses:

Low Suspect
Moderately Suspect
Highly Suspect
Multiple Active Accounts - Do Not Remove

based on logic below:

The "Multiple Active Accounts - Do Not Remove" status is applicable when a record in the:
- "Active Accounts" column has a value greater than 1 
and 
- values in the rest 3 columns (No Account (blanks), No Account Status (NULL)) do not matter.

The "Highly Suspect" status is applicable when a record in the:
- "Active Accounts" column has a value of 0
and
- values in the in the rest 3 columns (No Account (blanks), No Account Status (NULL)) do not matter.

The "Low Suspect" status is applicable when a record in the:
- "Active Accounts" column has a value of 1
and
- Former Account column has a value of 0
- values in the rest 2 columns (No Account (blanks), No Account Status (NULL)) do not matter.

This is how I want my the Outcome Analyses to be populated: 
[This is how I want my the Outcome Analyses to be populated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcCuI.png)

and this is what have now: 
[current table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YNfi.png)

Comment: Nested IF() functions would be the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can be done using nested `IF`

```
=IF(C2>1,"Multiple Active Accounts - Do Not Remove",IF(C2=0,"Highly Suspect",IF(AND(C2=1, D2=0),"Low Suspect","NA")))
```

Comment: since I noticed that data in my Base table I do not have AccountStatus equals to "Former" I do not need to use this logic only:=IF(C2>1,"Nultiple Active Accounts - Do Not Remove",IF(C2=0,"Highly Suspect"),IF(C2=1,"Low Suspect", "N/A")), but when I using it excel displays this message: "You've entered too many arguments for this function".

Comment: I got it, I simplified the formula to =IF(C2>1,"Nultiple Active Accounts - Do Not Remove",IF(C2=0,"Highly Suspect","Low Suspect"))

Comment: Accept this answer as it's already worked for you. It will be helpful to other